# EntityFramework: "Parameter value is out of range."

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a problem with saving a decimal in EntityFramework (Model First).
In my EDMX I declared my proprierty as a Decimal(30,10) then I tried to save the number: 
'1215867935736100000'

The result is:

```
Parameter value '1215867935736100000' is out of range.
```

I tried to make an INSERT query with SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyColumn) VALUES (1215867935736100000)
```

and the record is saved correctly.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: What is the data type generated on the table in sql server?

Comment: I think same issue has been solved here, follow link below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455547/sql-server-decimal30-10-losing-last-2-decimals

Comment: Your precision is far too large. What type of data are you storing in that column? You should get yourself familiar with how [precision, scale & length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) works in SQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an issue with the version of EF that you are using.

I have a code first version of the problem and can almost reproduce the error you are getting. The error I get includes a .00 in the message

> {"Parameter value '1215867935736100000.00' is out of range."}

The way I solved it was to add `.HasPrecision(30,10)` to the `EntityTypeConfiguration` class.

```
this.Property(t => t.value)
    .HasColumnName("value")
    .HasPrecision(30,10) //this line resolves the problem in my test code
    .IsRequired();
```

This doesn't fix your problem but I can at least confirm it is possible for Entity Framework to write the value `1215867935736100000` to the database.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable1](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [value] [decimal](30, 10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The test code:

```
MyContext testTableContext = new MyContext();
TestTable1 testTable1 = new TestTable1();
testTable1.value = 1215867935736100000;
testTableContext.TestTable1.Add(testTable1);
testTableContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: SQL server doesn't recognize the `m` suffix, that's used by C# to differentiate between a `double`/`decimal` (or `float`).

Comment: @james the title and the tags mention a thing called `Entity Framework` and @Enthuns has stated he can insert the data with raw Sql - a C# solution is required. Try reading the question.

Comment: Firstly, I have read the question. Secondly, the point you make in your answer is only applicable if the number is a *real* literal i.e. contains decimal places (which this value is not). Thirdly, the issue is on trying to save to the DB, not populating the EF model, therefore it indicates an issue at the DB server not the client.