# T-SQL multiplication decimal precision loss on insert (revisited)

Tags: sql-server-2012

please consider the following T-SQL code:

```
USE [Some.Database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[davetest](
    [factor1] [decimal](20, 8) NULL,
    [factor2] [decimal](20, 8) NULL,
    [factor3] [decimal](20, 8) NULL,
    [answer] [decimal](20, 8) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Now, consider this:

```
SELECT CAST( 0.11970939 * 0.07237864 *  0.0873142 AS decimal(20,8)) -- returns 0.00075653
```

Finally, check out these two update commands, using the same values:

```
  UPDATE davetest
  SET factor1 = 0.11970939,
  factor2 = 0.07237864,
  factor3 = 0.0873142

  UPDATE davetest
  SET answer = CAST( factor1 * factor2 * factor3 AS decimal(20,8))  -- answer is now 0.00075700
```

So... the problem is... unwanted rounding, to 6 decimal places, when I'd like to get 8 decimal places.  I'm getting 0.00075700, when I really want 0.00075653.

I've seen similar posts which sound fairly definitive, particularly this:

[Sql Server Decimal(30,10) losing last 2 decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455547/sql-server-decimal30-10-losing-last-2-decimals)

But that doesn't help me.  I've tried widening the precision, casting as various things, I've tried casting the input values before doing the multiplication, etc; none of that is really giving me the desired answer.

Obviously the act of doing an UPDATE into a decimal column of the same precision is giving me a different answer from a simple SELECT statement; from the other post and similar posts, I've got a sense of why it's happening; the question is, how can I get the same answer when I do the UPDATE, as I'm getting in the SELECT ?

Any help appreciated.  Many thanks.
Dave

Comment: This isn't really an answer as I can't explain the reasoning SQL does this. But if you have this as your update you get the expected results.       `UPDATE davetest
  SET answer = CAST( factor1 * factor2 AS decimal(20,8))  * factor3`   The problem happens when you multiple 3 sets of numbers together, when multipling only 2, you get the correct results.

Comment: Wow, how interesting.  That seems absolutely bizarre.  But you're right, it works.  Thanks very much for that.  I'll take it.